# JAXB @XmlElements, different types but same name?

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I have an Animal class and an extension of Animal called AnimalExtension.

```java
public class Animal

public class AnimalExtension extends Animal
```

The only difference between the two classes is that AnimalExtension has another instance variable called animalId. Animal does not have this instance variable.

I also have my own data type that I want to marshal and unamarshal to XML. This data type is called AnimalList. inside AnimalList, there is a list of Animals as an instance variable.

```java
@XmlType(name = "AnimalList")
public class AnimalList{
    private List<Animal> animalList;
    ....
```

animalList can contain both Animal and AnimalExtension. However, on the XML I dont want the element to be named as AnimalExtension; I want them all to have element name of Animal. I only want the extra attribute to show up when JAXB knows that the Animal is actually an instance of AnimalExtension. So if I have a list of that looks like

```java
List<Animal> animalList = new LinkedList<Animal>();
AnimalExtension animalExtension = new AnimalExtension();
animalExtension.setAnimalId(1);
amimalExtension.setName("Don");

Animal animal = new Animal();
animal.setName("Mike");
animalList.add(animalExtension);
animalList.add(animal);
```

I want the XML to look like

```java
<AnimalList>
   <Animal name="Don" id="1" />
   <Animal name="Mike" />
</AnimalList>
```

This is what I have tried to do

```java
    @XmlElements(
    {
            @XmlElement(name = "Animal", type = Animal.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "Animal", type = AnimalExtension.class)
        }
    )
    public List<Animal> getEntries() {
        return animalList;
    }
```

The code compiles but when I try running my server. It gives me this weird error that is so unrelated to what is going on (BeanCreationException). I tried making the name of the XmlElement to be different for each type and that works, but the challenge here is to make the name the same.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'encryptionPayloadContentProvider'
```

Comment: Given an XML how is JAXB supposed to determine which class to use for Java object creation? Is it existence of `id` attribute? What if there was other class named `AnimalEnhacement` with id attribute?

Comment: good point lol. didnt think of that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To map this use case you could leverage the following XmlAdapters:

**AnimalAdapter**

Since AnimalExtension is a super set of Animal we will use it to produce/consume XML. Then we will leverage the value of the animalId property to determine if an instance of Animal or AnimalExtension will be returned to AnimalList.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class AnimalAdapter extends XmlAdapter<AnimalExtension, Animal> {

    @Override
    public Animal unmarshal(AnimalExtension animalExtension) throws Exception {
        if(0 != animalExtension.getAnimalId()) {
            return animalExtension;
        }
        Animal animal = new Animal();
        animal.setName(animalExtension.getName());
        return animal;
    }

    @Override
    public AnimalExtension marshal(Animal animal) throws Exception {
        if(animal.getClass() == AnimalExtension.class) {
            return (AnimalExtension) animal;
        }
        AnimalExtension animalExtension = new AnimalExtension();
        animalExtension.setName(animal.getName());
        return animalExtension;
    }

}
```

**IdAdapter**

We will need a second XmlAdapter to suppress animalId if its value is 0:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class IdAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer unmarshal(String string) throws Exception {
        return Integer.valueOf(string);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Integer integer) throws Exception {
        if(integer == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return String.valueOf(integer);
    }

}
```

Your model classes will be annotated as follows:

**AnimalList**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement(name="AnimalList")
public class AnimalList {

    private List<Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<Animal>();

    @XmlElement(name="Animal")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AnimalAdapter.class)
    public List<Animal> getEntries() {
        return animalList;
    }

}
```

**Animal**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

public class Animal {

    private String name;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**AnimalExtension**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

public class AnimalExtension extends Animal {

    private int animalId;

    @XmlAttribute(name="id")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(IdAdapter.class)
    public int getAnimalId() {
        return animalId;
    }

    public void setAnimalId(int animalId) {
        this.animalId = animalId;
    }

}
```

**Demo Code**

The following demo code can be used to demonstrate this solution:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(AnimalList.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("input.xml");
        AnimalList animalList = (AnimalList) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        for(Animal animal : animalList.getEntries()) {
            System.out.println(animal.getClass());
        }

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(animalList, System.out);
    }

}
```

The following output will be produced:

```
class AnimalExtension
class Animal
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AnimalList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Animal name="Don" id="1"/>
   <Animal name="Mike"/>
</AnimalList>
```

**Related Information**

You may find the following information useful:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html