# Unmarshalling to a subclass with JAXB

Tags: jaxb

I've a JSON something like this:

```
objects:[{
   id:"p452365",
   type:"photo",
   link:"http://xxx.zz"
},
{
   id:"v7833",
   type:"video",
   link:"http://xxx.yy",
   length:"4.12"
}
]
```

In superclass `Entity`, there're 2 instance variables: id and type. In my extended `XmlAdapter` class I tried to cast my Entity instances to a subtype for ex. `Photo`

```
public HashMap<String, List<Column>> unmarshal(Feeds f) throws Exception {
        for(Feed feed : f.getFeeds()){
            System.out.println("Entity id for feed : " + feed.getId());
            for(Entity e:feed.getObjects()){
                if (e instanceof Photo){
                    // Of course it's not
                }
            }
        }
        return (HashMap<String, List<Column>>)fm.map(f.getFeeds());
    }
```

Of course e isn't an instanceof Photo, I took a shot there.:)
What I wanna do is to interfere the JAXB process sometime and unmarshall according to the type value in JSON.I wonder where and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my previous answers to a similar question may help here.  Essentially it is using the @XmlDescrimatorNode in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy).  Note I'm the MOXy tech lead.

- [Java/JAXB: Unmarshall Xml to specific subclass based on an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992234/java-jaxb-unmarshall-xml-to-specific-subclass-based-on-an-attribute/3181871#3181871)

You could also do this with an XmlAdapter.  AdaptedEntity would have all the properties from Entity and it's subclasses.

- [JAXB @XmlElements, different types but same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007516/jaxb-xmlelements-different-types-but-same-name/5042507#5042507)

Comment: Before I change the JAXB impl, I'd really like to give the second option a try.Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I've changed my mind.Now I'm working with MOXy.I put the jaxb.properties file into the package where my domain classes locate. But I'm getting this exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.Do you have any idea?Btw I'm currently using RestEasy.