# 2 JAXB @XmlElements with the same name different returnType class

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

I have 1 request (reqAccountValidate3) with 2 request definitions how to execute the request. Either you validate with cardNo, pinBlock and cardType where all 3 fields are mandatory:

```
<request>
    <reqClientAuth>
        <user>user</user>
        <password>password</password>
    </reqClientAuth>
    <reqAccountValidate3>
        <cardNo>cardNo</cardNo>
        <pinBlock>pinBlock</pinBlock>
        <cardType>cardType</cardType>
    </reqAccountValidate3>
</request>
```

or just with cardNo and pin where all 2 fields are mandatory:

```
<request>
    <reqClientAuth>
        <user>user</user>
        <password>password</password>
    </reqClientAuth>
    <reqAccountValidate3>
        <cardNo>cardNo</cardNo>
        <pin>pin</pin>
    </reqAccountValidate3>
</request>
```

I have a request wrapper where all requests (such as reqAccountValidate3) are held and their classes are anotated with their request names. It would be very handy for me if I could map this request in 2 separate classes (having 2 different versions of the same request) and have them annotated with same XmlElement name. I understand that this is in general not possible, but is there way how to make this happen? I was looking at very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007516/jaxb-xmlelements-different-types-but-same-name), but wanted to know if I am going wrong way about this.

Comment: I think the answer to the question you linked to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007516/jaxb-xmlelements-different-types-but-same-name) is the right approach for you.   I admit it is my answer.